# Modify address location inside WSDL File With PHP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I'm stuck in the problem, I'm getting a WSDL file from a web services provider but it have different address inside WL5G3N3:address location=

```
</WL5G3N0:operation>
</WL5G3N0:binding>
<WL5G3N0:service name="ReceiveSmsService">
<WL5G3N0:port binding="WL5G3N4:ReceiveSmsBinding" name="ReceiveSms">
<WL5G3N3:address location="http://xxx/xx?WSDL"/>
</WL5G3N0:port>
</WL5G3N0:service>
```

& obviously I don't have access to that specified address directly, I need to go through a load balancer so how can I change this address each time a php call that wsdl file ? Or How can I modify that once & save then in cache 
Please Help